# nmake: adding a prefix with inference rules?

Tags: prefix, nmake, inference

I'm using nmake inference rules successfully for file extensions -- but what about adding a file prefix? I'm doing qt stuff, so given a list of files eg

MOCS=moc_file1.cpp moc_file2.cpp

I want to find an an inference rule to get .h filenames to use as input to moc.exe and create the .cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

NMAKE inference rules allow specifying prefixes to the extensions referred in the rule. E.g.:

```
{$(SRCDIR)}.cpp{$(INTDIR)}.obj :
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) /Fo$@  /c $<
```

this rule would get triggered for [inferred] targets like:

```
"$(INTDIR)\somefile.obj" : "$(SRCDIR)\somefile.cpp"
```

Notice the use of {} braces to enclose the prefixes.

Similarly, an NMAKE inference *batch* rule (works on multiple source files at once):

```
{$(SRCDIR)}.cpp{$(INTDIR)}.obj ::
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) /Fo"$(INTDIR)"\  /c $<
```

Check out the official NMAKE docs -- they're still applicable even to VS2012.